# Using ggplot2 to draw bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I hope to make graph like this:
[image from a journal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QiZi.jpg)

My data is like:

```
temp<-data.frame(agecat=c("40-49","40-49","50-59","50-59","60+","60+"),
                  ANY=c("NO","YES","NO","YES","NO","YES"),
                  median=c(0.81,0.83,0.78,0.83,0.84,0.89),
                  up=c(1.2,1.25,1.25,1.31,1.44,1.34),
                  down=c(0.53,0.41,0.41,0.47,0.56,0.69))
```

(the HIV in graph is like ANY in my figures)

I tried the code below, it doesn't work.

```
ggplot(temp,aes(agecat,median,group=ANY,color=ANY,LABEL=round(median)))+geom_point()+facet_grid(~ANYPLAQ+agecat, scales="free", space="free")+geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=down,ymax=up),width=0.2)
```

I could only get figure like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pdk9.png)

I hope the width between each column are different for within age group and between age groups.

Could someone give me some suggestions, thanks!!

Comment: Start by getting rid of the `facet_grid`, which is a tool for splitting one chart into several charts.  When I try `ggplot(temp, aes(agegroup,median,group=ANY,color=ANY,LABEL=round(median))) + geom_point() + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=down,ymax=up),width=0.2)`, I get something which is starting to resemble your desired graph.  I would suggest changing your question to omit any mention of `facet_grid`, and include the actual picture of the chart in the question.

Comment: Also, your `temp` data uses variable `agegroup` while your code uses `agecat`.  Make them consistent, please.

Comment: @lebelinoz thanks for your suggestion!, but I really don't know how to add actual picture in the post, instead of the picture link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell what's going on, as the variables in the data frame you gave are different from the variables used in `ggplot()` call, but many faceting errors in ggplot can be resolved by calling `as.factor(your_variable)`. For example `facet_grid(~as.factor(ANYPLAQ) + as.factor(agecat)` hope this helps, next time be more specific.

Comment: Thank!! I made a mistake of the variable name in the data, and specified my question.